# Problema ao manipular Array

Tags: javascript, array

##### Estou tentando formas de fazer um carrinho de compras funcional

Meu carrinho de compras fica alocado no `localStorage`. O botão **adicionar produtos** funciona perfeitamente. Porém, gostaria de fazer um `push` condicional, caso já exista o mesmo produto dentro do `array` de objetos, ele incremente +1 quantidade e **NÃO** criar um novo objeto, evitado gerar um objeto repetido, para que assim eu possa renderizar a página com os produtos selecionados x quantidade de cada.

Por exemplo:

| Produto | Quantidade |
| --- | --- |
| iPad | 1 |
| TV | 1 |
| Celular | 2 |

- O que preciso fazer?
- Tentei usando `filter`, `find`, `includes`. Mas não consigo aplicar no minhas ideias no código.

```html
<!-- a função é um onclick de um produto(objeto). -->
<button onclick="addCarrinhos('<%= produtos.nome %>', document.getElementById('qtd').value, '<%= produtos.valor %>','<%= produtos.id %>')">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button>
```

```js
function addCarrinhos(produto, qtd, valor, id) {

//neste bloco, eu capturo os valores do meu objeto
    const produtos = {
        nomeProduto: produto,
        quantidade: qtd,
        valorProduto: valor,
        id: id
    }

//aqui verifico se está em branco, mas irei retirar depois, por que é inutil no meu codigo
    if (produtos === '') {
        alert('é necessário informar')

//neste bloco ele adiciona o produto caso o valor de localStorage seja nulo convertendo para string
    } else {
        if (localStorage.getItem('produtos') === null) {
            let listaProdutos = [produtos]
            localStorage.setItem('produtos', JSON.stringify(listaProdutos));

//neste bloco eu transformo  em objeto a string alocada no localStorage com o parse
        } else {
        let listaProdutos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('produtos'));
//aqui faço push do novo produto pra dentro de listaProdutos            
            listaProdutos.push(produtos);
//neste bloco faço um map, para retornar um novo array convertendo algumas strings para inteiros
            let novoObjeto = Object.assign(listaProdutos.map(e => {
                e.nomeProduto = e.nomeProduto
                e.quantidade = parseInt(e.quantidade)
                e.valorProduto = parseInt(e.valorProduto)
                e.id = parseInt(e.id)

                return e
            }))
//aqui eu crei um novo array, que vai conter o retorno do novoObjeto
            let novos = []
            novos.push(novoObjeto)
        }
//neste bloco adiciono no localStorage, o novo array
        localStorage.setItem('produtos', JSON.stringify(novos[0]))
        console.log('push funcionou')
    }
}
```

Comment: Já rodou no `console` do seu navegador? apresentou algum erro? coloquei sua função para rodar no meu e apresentou alguns erros, para que possamos lhe ajudar, nos dê mais detalhes (veja [como criar um Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Olá amigo, sim eu rodo a função tranquilamente.
Vou comentar o que cada bloco faz no comentario acima.

Comment: Creio que o erro era a falta do "produtos" em:
  let listaProdutos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('produtos'));

Comment: Não use o localStorage, mantenha o carrinho de compras no servidor. O trivial hoje é utilizar múltiplos dispositivos por exemplo eu uso o desktop ou notebook para escolher os itens e finalizo compra com o celular. Se carrinho de compras ficar no localStorage é publico a quem entrar na página a partir do dispositivo esteja logado ou não, será compartilhado entre todos os diferentes login feitos no site a partir do dispositivo,  não poderá ser utilizado em outros dispositivos e  está sujeito aos limites, restrições de memória e politicas impostas pelo o OS ao localStorage.

Comment: Olá augusto boa taarde, tudo bem? Poderia me dar um exemplo de usar servidor? Originalmente eu tinha intençao de usar o carrinho no banco de dados, mas ainda não aprendi a criar um usuaario temorario. Poderia me encaminhar por favor?
Ou algum lugar aqui dentro do stack, e afins?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Você está esquecendo de VALIDAR antes de inserir!

É de extrema importância a validação dos **campos**, **variáveis**, **etc** antes de inseri-los no **banco de dados**, ou como no seu caso, no `localStorage`.

O hábito do mal uso das propriedades e funções do JavaScript é que faz você pecar na hora de aplicar seu código! Vai por mim, experiência própria! sair usando as funções e propriedades sem ao menos saber COMO ELAS FUNCIONAVAM!!

Por isso, sugiro que veja exemplos do uso do [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Os aproveite bastante, veja seus parâmetros, USE E ABUSE da [**`documentação da MDN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/) isso lhe trará uma visão massa! Pois assim você saberá como e quando utiliza-las. (*também sugiro que NÃO deixe de ver [Como criar um Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) além de evitar fechamentos e negações, faz com que possamos lhe ajudar com sua dúvida mais rápido!*)

---

#### Seguindo conforme sua pergunta...

Criei uma variável responsável por **verificar** se já existe ou não um produto dentro do `array` de produtos. Fiz o uso do [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) retornando um valor booleano.

```js
let checarSeExiste = listaProdutos.filter(item => 
                (item.produto === produto)).length > 0; // retorna true ou false
```

##### Portanto, realizei alguns ajustes no seu código...

Para rodar no console do meu navegador, o mesmo ficou assim:

```js
// alterei o nome da função para entrar no contexto de adição de produtos!
function addProduto(produto, quantidade, valor) { // alterei a nomenclatura dos parâmetros para facilitar a leitura do código..
    const produtos = {
        produto:produto,
        quantidade:quantidade,
        valor:valor
    };
    // aqui o método vai retornar somente as chaves (ou melhor os produtos) falso caso não exista!
    if (!Object.keys(produtos).length) {
        alert("é necessário informar!");
    } else {
        // verifica se existe o item no localStorage
        if (localStorage.getItem("produtos") === null) {
            // cria um item com o objeto indexado (passa a ser uma chave filho)
            localStorage.setItem("produtos", JSON.stringify([produtos])); 
        } else {
            // obtêm o conteúdo do item produtos do localStorage
            let listaProdutos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("produtos"));
            // percorre todo o array e verifica se existe um produto semelhante ao que foi passado no parâmetro da função.
            let checarSeExiste = listaProdutos.filter(item => 
                (item.produto === produto)).length > 0; // retorna true ou false

            // valida se o retorno booleano é true (caso sim, dar continuidade)
            if (checarSeExiste) {
                // percorre todo o array porém, condiciona a um possível produto existente, se sim, ele vai retornar
                // um novo array com o novos valores, isto é, a quantidade (observação: serve para qualquer propriedade)
                listaProdutos.map(items => {
                    if (items.produto === produto)
                        items.quantidade += Number(quantidade); // soma o valor existente mais a quantidade repassada na função
                    return items;
                });
            } else {
                // não existindo ele adiciona!
                listaProdutos.push(produtos);
            }

            // e por fim, não incrementa, mas sobrescreve todo o conteúdo presente no item produtos do localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("produtos", JSON.stringify(listaProdutos));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja o resultado: [**teste o código**](https://playcode.io/917568/)

Comment: Olá meu amigo, tudo beleza? Muito obrigado pela dica vou rodar o codigo daqui a pouco pq hoje o dia foi punk pra mim, e não consegui entrar no pc ainda.

Comment: Tudo bem, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição, se a solução serviu para vc, considere votar +1 na resposta!

Comment: Opa amigo, teste o codigo, e alterei apenas nesse trecho:
listaProdutos.map(items => {
                    
                    if (items.produto === produto)
                    items.nomeProduto = items.nomeProduto
                    items.quantidade = parseInt(items.quantidade)
                    items.valor = parseInt(items.valor)
                    items.id = parseInt(items.id)
                        items.quantidade += Number(quantidade); // soma o valor existente mais a quantidade repassada na função
                    return items;
                });

Comment: No codigo que voce me passou, ele estava passando como string o valor. Então coloquei, o parseint. Mas é isso mesmo que eu queria, o amigo de cima me disse que existe outro meio melhor para salvar essa informação, voce sabe qual seria?
Falta apenas arrumar o carrinho e comunicar com o banco de dados quando o usuario fechar o pedido.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Comment: Fiz isso agora, sou novo no forum. Muito obrigado de verdade abriu um leque gigante pra mim essa validação com filter, ficou excelente!!

Comment: Obrigado! e antes de mais nada, não somos um fórum e sim e um site de perguntas de respostas, veja [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum)